# In App Purchase - Failed transaction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm trying to implement In App Purchase in my app. The type is Non-Consumable.
The produtct request reuturns fine..with correct title, description and price. But when I click to buy, open the alertView saying "confirm....Environment:Sandbox" when I click in confirm, should appears the apple box requesting the password from user test..but It doesn't appears and the tansaction failed without message error... My app isn't in AppStore yet and the In App Purchase Product in Itunes Connect has the status **Ready to Submit** It's correct?

Here is My code: (Sorry for longer code, but I mean that its relevant and important for my question)

```
 - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
 {
NSArray *products = response.products;
proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain] : nil;
if (proUpgradeProduct)
{
    NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
    NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
    NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
    NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);

    //        lblTitulo.text = proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier;
    //        lblDescricao.text = proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription;

}

for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
}

// finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
[productsRequest release];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"versaopro" ];
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];

// we will release the request object in the delegate callback
 }
 - (void)loadStore
{
// restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

// get the product description (defined in early sections)
[self requestProUpgradeProductData];
}

    - (void)purchaseProUpgrade
 {
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:proUpgradeProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
   }



-(IBAction) buyClick: (id) sender {
[self purchaseProUpgrade];
  }
```